# Select all rows only if the count of rows found matches the number of "arguments" used

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's assume I have the following table `my_table`:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Tyler |
| 2 | Earl |
| 3 | Frank |
| 4 | Jasper |

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT mt.* FROM my_table AS mt WHERE mt.name IN ('Earl', 'Jasper');
```

that outputs

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Earl |
| 4 | Jasper |

However, I only want to return something when the count of rows is equal to the count of names. So

```
SELECT mt.* FROM my_table AS mt WHERE mt.name IN ('Earl', 'John');
```

should output an empty query, instead of

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Earl |

**TL;DR**: I want a query to return all rows **only** if the count of rows found matches the number of arguments used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can collect all found names and then check if that matches the number you want:

```
select id, name
from (
  select *, 
         array_agg(name) over () as all_names
  from the_table
  where name in ('Earl', 'Frank')
) t
where cardinality(all_names) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
WITH list AS
( SELECT *
    FROM my_table AS t
   RIGHT JOIN unnest(array['Earl', 'John']) AS a(val)
      ON a.val = t.name
)
SELECT *
  FROM list
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM list WHERE id IS NULL)
```

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=dad6b3ecf18f164babd09361e22905fd).

Answer (score 1):

If you are all right with the syntax, you can pass your query names in as a text array:

```
with inlist as (
  select '{"Earl", "Jasper"}'::text[] as q
), init_match as (
  select t.id, t.name, cardinality(i.q) as qlen, count(1) over () as matchlen
    from inlist i
         join my_table t
           on t.name = any(i.q)
)
select * 
  from init_match
 where qlen = matchlen;
```

[working fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6ae24627872c5913ebb4c495df547e8b)